# SQL Server replication using triggers

Tags: sql, replication

I have two databases (`db1,db2`) that reside on different servers, `db1` resides on `dbserver1`, `db2` on `dbserver2`.

Now I want to replicate data from `db1` (old schema) to the new schema in `db2` in REAL TIME. What is the best/most efficient approach here?

The first thing comes to my mind are triggers, is it possible to have trigger in `db1` that inserts/updates record to `db2`? Is there any other approach? thanks..

```
         [db1.OldSchema] => [db2.NewSchema]
```

ADDITIONAL: this only one way sync, because db2 will be used only in reporting..

Comment: I'd advise looking at the various built in solutions for replication. You've asked for "Real Time", but I doubt you need that, and it's a lot less expensive if you're requirements are, say "within 5 minutes" (especially if, as you say, it's for reporting purposes). You also need to consider what happens if DB2 is unreachable from DB1 for any reason (e.g. network, server restart, etc). With a trigger-based solution, DB1 would become unusable.

Comment: youre right it's not really real time, actually we need to sync the data every 1 hour at the most, looks like using SSIS is the way to go.. thanks... Is SSIS compatible replicating data from SQL 2000 to 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably best for [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com), but short answer is that there's a variety of methods you can use:

1. Scheduled backup/restores (if you're
   happy to blow away your 2nd DB on
   each restore)
2. Log shipping (passes over changes since last updated)
3. SSIS package (if you need to change the structure of the database ie: transform, then this is a good method, if the structure is the same use one of the other methods)
4. [Replication](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-replication-crib-sheet/) (as you seem to want 1 way, I'd suggest transactional replication, this is the closest you'll probably get to real time, but should not be entered into lightly as it will have impacts on how you work with both databases)